# Display checkboxes vertically with labels next to each

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to display checkboxes vertically with their labels to the right of each, but can't seem to get the formatting correct.

**Example of what I am trying to do:**

*Checkbox 1 Label 1*

*Checkbox 2 Label 2*

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<form class="addmod" method="post">
<table width="800px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label><h5>Version Compatibility:</h5></label>
 </td>
<td><input name="v162" type="checkbox" id="v162" value="1.6.2"><label><h5>1.6.2</h5></label></td>
<td><input name="v164" type="checkbox" id="v164" value="1.6.4"><label><h5>1.6.4</h5></label></td>
<td><input name="v172" type="checkbox" id="v172" value="1.7.2"><label><h5>1.7.2</h5></label></td>
```

**and the CSS:**

```
.addmod {
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 400px;
}

#add input {
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
padding: 10px 5px;
font: bold 15px Calibri;
border: 0;
background: #FFF;
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.addmod label {
text-align: left;
display: inline;
}

.addmod td {
text-align: center;
}

.addmod input[type=checkbox] {
display: block;
}
```

**Here's a jsFiddle for this:** http://jsfiddle.net/swiftsly/syvY4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `.addmod input` and `.addmod label` to `inline-block` and add `display: block` to `td`.

**CSS**

```
.addmod label {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.addmod td {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
.addmod input[type=checkbox] {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syvY4/4/